# Column string format

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, string-formatting

I found how to use `StringFormat` from `XAML` but I need to add columns *programmatically* and I can't find a solution for it. The code I am using doesn't work:

```
foreach (Fields field in fields)
{
    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
    column.Header = field.name;
    column.Binding = new Binding(field.name) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
    if (field.group[0] == "<numbers>" && field.group.Count == 1)
        column.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:d}";
    dgwDataMain.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: What I normally do is take the DataTable, add columns there and then setting the datagridview.DataSource to the DataTable again. But that also requires re-adding all the data. Do you need to add the columns after the table is shown or just after getting it from the database?

Comment: What exactly means "doesn't work"? Maybe a stupid question, but do you actually add items to the DataGrid, or just columns?

Comment: @MrFox I need to add columns every time I get data from MySql (it refreshes)

Comment: @Clemens I can write anything (formatting isn't a rule)

Comment: I see and I can edit them but I want only to be able to type integer values, not any value in the specific column.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
column.Binding =
    new Binding(field.name)
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    };
```

`UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` causes the binding source to be update on each typed character. Hence the input is validated each time.

The default [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) value for the `TextBox.Text` property (used by a DataGrid cell) is `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus`.

Comment: Ok abut I have never used this. What to do after that? :D

Comment: Sorry, but i really don't know what you mean. You wrote "I can edit them but I want only to be able to type integer values" which makes me assume that the column is bound to an integer value. If so, binding validation should fail if you type something that is not an integer.

Comment: Used: column.Binding = new Binding(field.name)
                        {
                            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                            StringFormat = "{0:d}"
                        };

and still can write any value.

Comment: The field should be of type `int`. Apparently it isn't. `Binding.StringFormat` just cares for formatting the binding source value, it does not define an input format.

Comment: And how can I achieve that please?

Comment: You might need to set a custom validation rule. Read about [Data Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_validation). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2632528/1136211) might also help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22589/discussion-between-ice-13-and-clemens)

Comment: Still can't find how to asign validation rule from code. It says that ValidationRule is read only if I use it in column binding {}.

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use a DataTable.
It's columns can be of any type, which is very hard with adding new DataGridColumn.

1. Collect all data.
2. Add columns of the right type to a DataTable.
3. Add all data to your DataTable.
4. Set dataGrid.DataSource = the DataTable;

Comment: If I use this I get empty rows. Maybe because my DataGrid has rows of a custom class type?

Comment: DataGrid rows don't have a type. The type is stored in columns, rows hold an array of objects of (hopefully) the right type. Can you look at the data from your database? Maybe some rows only have nulls.

Comment: Please analyze the situation, what is the actual problem? Are empty rows being inserted? Or is information missing leading to empty rows? I can keep asking these questions all day, you should ask them yourself and figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I use a custom class source to populate the table. If I also add a source for it's columns before populating the table, it shows me small empty lines (no headers for columns too).

Answer (score 0):

You Should try In Your Xaml Code

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Full date/time pattern (short time): "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=f, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Full date/time pattern (long time): "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=F, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Short date/time pattern (short time): "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=g, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Short date/time pattern (long time): "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=G, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Or

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="In Currency with zero decimal point: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=\{0:c0\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="In Currency with two decimal point: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=\{0:c2\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

or

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Normal Number: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Number, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Above number with 2 decimal point: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=\{0:n2\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Above number with 4 decimal point: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=\{0:n4\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Above number with 10 Zero place holder: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=\{0:0000000000\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

or

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Normal string: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="String with atleast 15 characters length: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat=\{0\,15\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="String with atleast 25 characters length: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat=\{0\,25\}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Text with quote: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat='The string &quot;\{0\}&quot; inside a quot',
                              ElementName=userControl}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you but I have already said that I need to add columns programmatically (from code) and the columns are constantly changing as user prefer so I can't set this from XAML.

Comment: I don't know the columns because the user is changing them and loading from a database so I can't pre-configure them.

Comment: Are You Using Silverlight 5 or 4 ?

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj Look at the tags, it's WPF, not Silverlight.